# AWS SES (mails) Callback on status changed

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, callback, amazon-ses

We use AWS SES to send messages. I'm setting up AWS to receive the status with an http request on ou services.

To achieve it, I use SNS. The SNS topic is triggered by 2 way provided by AWS :

[image: Configuration set]

First, as you can see in the picture, is the configuration ruleset, affected to the concerned email address.

[image]

Second is in the notification panel of the address.

First method offers more status, but I can't include the mail's headers.

So my questions :

- I use the mail's headers to pass the ID of the mail and update the status in my DB. Could I get the ID used by AWS by an other way? I send the mail using a "MailMessage" object provided by the .net library.
- Can I send the mail's header while retrieving detailed status such as click tracking?

Comment: Did you check this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/event-publishing-retrieving-sns-contents.html